# Html.ActionLink syntax error

Tags: actionlink

I want to change this

```
<a class="more" href="Subject?SubjectId=@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Id)">Devamı &raquo;</a>
```

to

```
<a class="more"@Html.ActionLink("Devamı ", "Subject", new {Subject?SubjectId= item.Id }) ></a>
```

I can not put &raquo and Subject?SubjectId= to @Html.actionlink.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at Microsoft's site, it says Html.ActionLink returns a complete anchor (`<a></a>`) object based on the parameters you give it.

You can't put the anchor returned by ActionLink into your anchor element. Choose one of the other ways of creating the link.

You may be looking for the Url.Action method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.108).aspx

```
<a class="more" href=@Url.Action("ControllerName", new {SubjectId = item.Id})
    >Devamı &raquo;
</a>
```

Comment: Can i put special characters (?!) by url.action ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'd need to. The point of the method is that it generates the path for you.
That includes the ? that's part of the query. You give it the controller, and query parameters/values, and it spits out a formatted 
app.com/Controller?Param=value